# Authorization Failed [Omnipay and Paypal]

Tags: php, paypal, laravel-5, omnipay

Authorization Failed

Here is my code:

```
$gateway = Omnipay::create('PayPal_Express');

        // Initialise the gateway
        $gateway->initialize(array(
            'clientId' => 'AZzCeImpURKHH0LIFSBTrEWGY-NKLCnUUQdHT049pRLvwBXg9BnlpbnsiGLPFQH43DU4eL-Qi96nrZU6',
            'secret' => 'EFP_mny9dfaaAfW1oyNM8R05weA5eIkU51KUSAdbvcoh3v4bo7txRBm-uzDZ2nOlZ0KmqS-JalgujFok',
            'testMode' => true, // Or false when you are ready for live transactions
        ));

        // Do an authorisation transaction on the gateway
        $transaction = $gateway->authorize(array(
            'returnUrl' => 'http://client.com',
            'cancelUrl' => 'http://localhost:8000/cancel',
            'amount' => '10.00',
            'currency' => 'AUD',
            'description' => 'This is a test authorize transaction.',
                // 'card'          => $card,
        ));

        $response = $transaction->send();
        if ($response->isSuccessful()) {
            // Find the authorization ID
            $authResponse = $response->getTransactionReference();
            echo "Authorize transaction was successful!\n" . $authResponse;
        } else {
            echo "Failed to auth transaction";
            dd($response);
        }

        // Once the transaction has been approved, we need to complete it.
        $transaction = $gateway->completePurchase(array(
            'payerId' => $request->PayerID,
            'transactionReference' => $authResponse
        ));

        $finalResponse = $transaction->send();

        dd($finalResponse);

        if ($finalResponse->getData()) {
            echo "Transaction was successful!\n";
            // Find the authorization ID
            $results = $finalResponse->getTransactionReference();
            dd($results);
        } else {
            dd($finalResponse->getData());
        }
```

I am trying to set up paypal sendbox with my laravel app. This code is in get method and when I call it I get:

```
Failed to auth transaction
ExpressAuthorizeResponse {#354 ▼
  #liveCheckoutEndpoint: "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
  #testCheckoutEndpoint: "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
  #request: ExpressAuthorizeRequest {#349 ▶}
  #data: array:9 [▼
    "TIMESTAMP" => "2016-02-12T15:06:21Z"
    "CORRELATIONID" => "68efe51d8aca6"
    "ACK" => "Failure"
    "VERSION" => "119.0"
    "BUILD" => "18308778"
    "L_ERRORCODE0" => "10002"
    "L_SHORTMESSAGE0" => "Authentication/Authorization Failed"
    "L_LONGMESSAGE0" => "You do not have permissions to make this API call"
    "L_SEVERITYCODE0" => "Error"
  ]
}
```

Anyone know what is problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error code being returned is 10002: `"L_ERRORCODE0" => "10002"`

The PayPal [API Error and Warning Codes](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/) document states:

> This error can be caused by an incorrect API username, an incorrect
>   API password, or an invalid API signature. Make sure that all three of
>   these values are correct. For your security, PayPal does not report
>   exactly which of these three values might be in error.

The API username and/or password is wrong.  Reset those and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of array that you're passing to the `initialize()` method is intended for REST API.

Change:

`$gateway = Omnipay::create('PayPal_Express');`

to:

`$gateway = Omnipay::create('PayPal_Rest');`

You can get a list of available parameters by calling `getDefaultParameters()` method.

For `PayPal_Rest` it will will give you:

```
array:4 [▼
  "clientId" => ""
  "secret" => ""
  "token" => ""
  "testMode" => false
]
```

and this for `PayPal_Express`:

```
array:10 [▼
  "username" => ""
  "password" => ""
  "signature" => ""
  "testMode" => false
  "solutionType" => array:2 [▶]
  "landingPage" => array:2 [▶]
  "brandName" => ""
  "headerImageUrl" => ""
  "logoImageUrl" => ""
  "borderColor" => ""
]
```